# OSX extension doesn't call tableView viewFor method

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstableview

I've set up a `Table View` to be displayed in an OSX extension. 
I  basically copied the code from the OSX `TableViewController`, I've then created the related interface in the .xib `TodayViewController`, connected the `tableView` from the `File's Owner` to the tableview component. 
I've also set `TodayViewController.xib` as `Main Interface` for the extension in the `General` panel

The problem is that when I run the extension the method `numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView)` is fired correctly, but not `tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)`. Hence my view is empty.

This is the set up I have

```
class TodayViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate, NCWidgetProviding  {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    override var nibName: NSNib.Name? {
        return NSNib.Name("TodayViewController")
    }

    func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Update your data and prepare for a snapshot. Call completion handler when you are done
        // with NoData if nothing has changed or NewData if there is new data since the last
        // time we called you
        completionHandler(.noData)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.headerView = nil

        tableView.target = self
        tableView.action = #selector(self.onItemClicked)

        tableView.isEnabled = true
        fetchData() // -> this method contains tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? { 
    // ...
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    // ...
    }
}
```

I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Is the table view view based (not cell based)? Which other `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` methods are implemented? Is anything logged to the console?

Comment: yep it's view based. The code I'm using is the exact same of the main osx app, the only problem is that the `viewFor` method is never called, while the `numberOfRows ` is. Which is strange

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that you are omitting the `tableView(objectValueFor:row:)` method from `NSTableViewDataSource`. As the documentation states:

> This method is mandatory unless your application is using Cocoa bindings for providing data to the table view.

`tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)` can be used to customize the view that will be used to display the object value, but if you never provide the object value in the first place, you'll never get that far.

On macOS, however, I would suggest looking into `NSArrayController` and Cocoa Bindings to populate your table view. In most cases, this is *significantly* easier to set up, and provides a lot of nice functionality for free as well.

Comment: thanks for your answer! :) I actually have this method which is set to return `nil`, hence the problem right? But I don't understand why this exact same code works on the main application. Is it because I'm using a storyboard there?

Comment: That'd be my guess. I don't know why this would work in the main app (it seems like it shouldn't), but it's been years since I used a manual `NSTableViewDataSource` on macOS. `NSArrayController` is just too convenient for that.

Comment: mmm I'll look into that. Anyway I checked and the `tableView(objectValueFor:row:)` method is never fired. So yeah, there should be another issue before that :D

Comment: That's odd, it should be getting called. Can you make sure that your `numberOfRows` isn't returning zero, or a negative value, or something?

Comment: yep, it's returning 1, which is the correct value from the data source. It's like it is not able to display itself. Probably I missed some links, I've almost never worked purely with .xib. Is it correct that I link the `tableView` to the `File's Owner` in the .xib interface, which is a `TodayViewController` class?

Comment: Do you have the `dataSource` outlet connected on the table view?

Comment: (and yes, File's Owner is the correct thing to point it at if you're using a view controller)

Comment: nope, I've set `tableView.dataSource = self` and I thought it was enough. Should I?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't notice that in the code sample. Yeah, that should set the data source. And because you have `tableView` declared with `!`, it should crash if it's nil, so it's probably not that. Hrm.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you possibly make a copy of your project, reduce it down to the minimum needed to repro the problem, and post it? I bet I could figure out what's going on if I could run it on my machine with the debugger attached.

Comment: mmm, I tried to remove the `tableview` both from code and .xib. Leaving just a label with "Hello" in the middle of the view. Guess what, nothing is rendered.. It looks like the UI is detached

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder and rebuilding?

Comment: Also since this is an extension, make sure you don't have any old versions of it lying around that might be getting loaded instead of your current one.